# linq join with less than or equal to int value

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I wanting to know the best approach for a where clause with less than or equal to where the value to match is int?

```
var outOfStockProducts = (from theMapProd in context.tblProductOptions_MAP
                          join theProd in context.tblProducts on theMapProd.productID equals theProd.productID
                          where theProd.stock_Level  <= 5
                          select theMapProd).ToList();
```

Comment: What's your concern with the query you've got?

Answer (score 0):

This is another way,
Not tested.

```
var outOfStockProducts = (from theMapProd in context.tblProductOptions_MAP
                      join theProd in context.tblProducts on theMapProd.productID equals theProd.productID
                      select theMapProd).ToList();

outOfStockProducts=outOfStockProducts.where(x=>x.stock_Level  < 5 || x.stock_Level ==5).ToList();
```

Comment: That's way worse than the original query